# Match Tabs in vim syntax file

Tags: regex, vim, syntax

I'm coding a syntax file for my todos with Vim
Actually i highlight the lines when they begin with w:,h: or p: like this :

```
syn match todoHome  "^h: "
syn match todoWork  "^w: "
syn match todoPersonal  "^p: "
syn region todoHome start=/^h: / end=/\n/
syn region todoWork start=/^w: / end=/\n/
syn region todoPersonal start=/^p: / end=/\n/
syn region todoDone start=/^x: / end=/\n/
```

I would like to create some subtask with tabs and highlight it in the same way... 
I know regex can do that, i tried :

```
syn region todoWork start=/^|[\t ]+w: / end=/\n/
```

But it not works... Any clue ?

Comment: probably a right pattern would be `/^\s*\zsw:/`. `\zs` delimits start of matched part. `\s` matches any whitespace (tab or space, `:help /\s`)

Comment: the pattern you give me don't really works.. i dig in the help and this works: /.*\zsh: 
As you can see the problem is that you can put any digit in front of the h:, p: or w:...

Comment: well this /\s\|^_*\zsh: seems to works pretty well :) But is there a way ti match only the tabs ? Not the spaces ?

Comment: ok i fund the correct pattern : /^_\|\s*\zsh: does the job perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` => `\|`

```
:help pattern

1. A pattern is one or more branches, separated by "\|".  It matches anything
   that matches one of the branches.  Example: "foo\|beep" matches "foo" and
   matches "beep".  If more than one branch matches, the first one is used.

   pattern ::=      branch
        or  branch \| branch
        or  branch \| branch \| branch
        etc.
```

`+` => `\+`

```
\+  1 or more   as many as possible (*)
```

---

### Or add `\v` at the beginning of the pattern!

```
Use of "\v" means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
'0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.  "very magic"
```

Comment: Note that `+` becomes also `\+`. Alternatively it is possible as specified in the same help section, to turn on the `verymagic` setting: then every character that might have a special meaning will have it. `/\v^|[\t]+w: /`